# Search for lines that contain X, but show more than this line when found

Tags: php, mysql, html, search, search-engine

Straight to the point:

In

```
ip ssh version 2
no aaa new-model
!
dot11 ssid lala
    vlan 500
    authentication open 
    authentication key-management wpa
    wpa-psk ascii 100 40345352352352352352255325
!
!
crypto pki trustpoint TP-self-signed-3007141781
```

I want for instance search for a keyword 'vlan'. My code returns 'vlan 500' which is correct. And it also returns all the lines where 'vlan' is.

Now I want the search program (php) to return the whole block. In above case:

```
!
dot11 ssid lala
    vlan 500
    authentication open 
    authentication key-management wpa
    wpa-psk ascii 100 40345352352352352352255325
!
```

or without '!' ofcourse.

Any ideas for acomplishing this fast and effective?

ps: For now i'm using

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)){
....
```

and

```
foreach(preg_split("/(\r?\n)/", $config) as $line){
...
```

in it, to get the lines where the search word appears.

Comment: I thought of saving index of every '!' to a variable and when the search word is found, the last index (each time i would overwrite it) would be the start of the block right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to achieve that by saving indexes of block startings. I got the block start by checking the spaces infront of each line, and the last block before I found the matching word was the index where I started to display lines.